# how to randomise questions with corresponding answers from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on making a quiz app and i am stuck at one point. I am using PHP and MySQL to make it. **So, i want now to randomise the retrieval of questions from the database** . But , when i try to use the **rand()** with the questions, it's choices are different from what it should be. **What should i do** to sync the randomness of the questions with the answers.

```
class Quiz {

protected $_db;
protected $_answers = array();
protected $_questions = array();
protected $_question;
protected $_users;
protected $_leaderboard;
protected $_currentuser;

public $session;

public function __construct(\Pimple $container)
{
    $this->_currentuser = $container['user'];

    $this->session = $container['session'];
    $this->_leaderboard = $container['leaderboard'];
    $this->_users = $this->_leaderboard->getMembers();

    try
    {
        //$this->_db = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::$dbhost.';dbname='.Config::$dbname,  Config::$dbuser,  Config::$dbpassword);
        $this->_db = $container['db'];
        $this->_populateQuestions();
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e)
    {
        return $e;
    }

}

public function getAnswers($questionid = false)
{   
    if ($questionid)
    {
        //pull answers from db for only this question
        $answersql = "SELECT text FROM answers where question_id = :id ORDER BY correct DESC";
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($answersql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $questionid, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($result = $stmt->fetchObject())
        {
           array_push($this->_answers,$result->text);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //pull all answers from db grouped by question
        $answersql = "SELECT group_concat( a.text ORDER BY a.correct DESC SEPARATOR '~' ) FROM answers a GROUP BY a.question_id";
        $stmt = $this->_db->query($answersql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultset = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        foreach ($resultset as $csv)
        {   
            $tmparray = explode('~', $csv[0]);
            array_push($this->_answers,$tmparray);
        }
    }

    return $this->_answers;
}


public function getQuestion($questionid) 
{
    $questionsql = "select text from questions where id = :id order by rand()";
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($questionsql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $questionid, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchObject();
    $this->_question = $row->text;

    return $this->_question;
}

public function getQuestions()
{
    return $this->_questions;
}

private function _populateQuestions() 
{
    $questionsql = "select text from questions order by id asc";
    $stmt = $this->_db->query($questionsql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject())
    {
        $this->_questions[] .= $row->text;
    }
}
```

Comment: `select text from questions where id = :id order by rand()` should retrieve only questions which have the `id` that you are passing. Are you sure that they are not the right questions?

Comment: what do you mean? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Randomize an array of the same length as your question and answer arrays, with the values as array indexes, then iterate over the quiz questions and answers and change their keys. The order will be the same for each. Here is an example:

```
$order = [1, 0];

$ques = ['foo', 'bar'];

$ans = ['baz', 'bop'];

$new_ques = [];
$new_ans = [];
foreach($order as $k=>$v){
    $new_ques[$v] = $ques[$k];
    $new_ans[$v] = $ans[$k];
}
ksort($new_ques);ksort($new_ans);

var_dump($new_ques, $new_ans);
```

This is slightly inefficient because it creates a new array to put the values on, and then sorts them, but it should work for what you need.